# Why is the overloaded function not called?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, overloading

I've written some code in C++ and compiled it in GNU C++11 compiler. I defined two functions using templates to sort a set of values with different data types. One is to swap values and another is to do sorting operation. And also I defined two overloaded functions of the functions I mentioned to sort C-strings. It looks I passed the required array contained C-strings entered by user correctly but I don't know why overloaded functions aren't calling.

This is my code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<conio.h>
#define TOTAL 3

template<typename swap>
void Swap(swap *value_1, swap *value_2)
{
    swap temp = *value_1;
    *value_1 = *value_2;
    *value_2 = temp;
}

void Swap(char *string_1, char *string_2)
{
    char temp[30];
    strcpy(temp, string_1);
    strcpy(string_1, string_2);
    strcpy(string_2, temp);
}

template<typename sort>
void Shellsort(sort *array, int Length)
{
    for(short int Step = Length / 2; Step != 0; Step--)
    {
        for(short int Counter = 0; (Counter + Step) != Length; Counter++)
        {
            if(*(array + Counter) > *(array + (Counter + Step)))
                Swap(*(array + Counter), *(array + (Counter + Step)));
        }
    }
}

void Shellsort(char **array, int Length)
{
    printf("Your value is string");
    system("pause");

    for(short int Step = Length / 2; Step != 0; Step--)
    {
        for(short int Counter = 0; (Step + Counter) != Length; Counter++)
        {
            if(strcmp(*(array + Counter), *(array + (Step + Counter))) > 0)
                Swap(*(array + Counter), *(array + (Step + Counter)));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char strings[TOTAL][30];

    for(int Counter = 0; Counter < TOTAL; Counter++)
    {
        printf("Number %hd: Enter the string: ", Counter + 1);
        fgets(*(strings + Counter), 30, stdin);
        system("cls");
    }

    Shellsort(strings, TOTAL);

    for(int Counter = 0; Counter < TOTAL; Counter++)
        printf("Number %hd: %s", Counter + 1, *(strings + Counter));
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C is not C++, they are separate languages.  There is no such programming language as C/C++..  Please don't tag C++ questions with C.

Comment: which overload did you expect to be called and which one is called instead?

Comment: Does C++ prefer an exact match on a template type like `char[3][30]` to a non-template function that requires decaying the array to a `char**` pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function is calling Shellsort with a `char (*)[30]` argument.  This does not match your `char **` overload, so it instantiates the template and calls that.